# What means check mark near classname in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I open project panel in PhpStorm ("Project" tab) and one of my classes is marked by check.

[image]

What does it mean? There are no errors in code, it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have the answer:

Seems like you have bookmarked the Standing.php file somehow. You can check it inside your favourites tool window: "Navigate => Bookmarks => Show Bookmarks".

The source of this answer can be found here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207284795-Tick-next-to-filename

Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't just link to an answer, explain it in yours. What if that link ever changes?

Comment: That's true, let me explain better then.